# Alternate CSS by database flag

Tags: css, database

I have some flags that I save in my database, each flag has a specific icon on my page.

like:

```
<div class="myClass">
 <i class="icon-flag1"></i>
 <i class="icon-flag2"></i>
 <i class="icon-flag3"></i>
</div>
```

Whenever the flag is on, e.g: it's '1'. I need to call the user's attention, the icon/flag will indicate that he needs to pay attention to this specific flag, by the icon and the hover pop-up I have the user will know what each icon means.

My problem is: How do I change the color of that element `<i class="icon-flag1"></i>` according to the database flag value ?
Or maybe is there an easier way to achieve this goal?

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: @KaranShah PHP, laravel framework

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's would be a good idea to create a generic class, for example `.icon-flag` which contains styles that will be applied to all of the icons, this way you're not repeating yourself, or using selectors like `.icon-flag1, .icon-flag-2, .icon-flag-3 {}`, etc. which should be used to set the individual icon (for example, a background image).

Then you'd add 'state' styles, for example `.active, .inactive` to change the font.

Here's an example:

```
// Common styles to all icons
.icon-flag {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  display: block;
}

 // State styles
.icon-flag.active { color: green; }
.icon-flag.inactive { color: red; }
.icon-flag.deleted { color: grey; font-style: italic; }

// You'd do your different icon backgrounds, etc in here.
//   .icon-flag-1 {}, .icon-flag-2 {}, .icon-flag-3 {}, etc...

<div id="icon-example-1">
  <i class="icon-flag icon-flag-1 active">1</i>
  <i class="icon-flag icon-flag-2 inactive">2</i>
  <i class="icon-flag icon-flag-3 deleted">3</i>
  <i class="icon-flag icon-flag-4 active">4</i>
  <i class="icon-flag icon-flag-5 deleted">5</i>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I use any of this according to database state? I'm using PHP in backend.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code snippet which shows how you can change an icons color based on some trigger in your website or app.

For demonstration purposes, my trigger here is **onMouseOver** so you can see it in action, in your own app it will of course be triggered by a MySQL query, signals, or the ID of the icon as you stated.

```js
$('#iconA').mouseover(function(){
   $('#iconA').addClass('isRED');
});

$('#iconB').mouseover(function(){
   $('#iconB').addClass('isGREEN');
});

$('#iconC').mouseover(function(){
   $('#iconC').addClass('isBLUE');
});
```

```css
.isRED { color: red; }
.isGREEN { color: green; }
.isBLUE { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="myClass">
 <i id="iconA" class="icon-flag1">X</i>
 <i id="iconB" class="icon-flag2">X</i>
 <i id="iconC" class="icon-flag3">X</i>
</div>
```

Alternatively, or let's say additionally, you can set the color class based on the id of the icon as follows:

```
if( $('#iconA').hasClass('icon-flag1') )
{
   $('#iconA').addClass('isRED');
} else if( $('#iconA').hasClass('icon-flag2') )
{
   $('#iconA').addClass('isGREEN');
} if( $('#iconA').hasClass('icon-flag3') )
{
   $('#iconA').addClass('isBLUE');
}
```

Comment: How do I use any of this according to database state?  
I'm using PHP in backend.

Comment: No offense, but i hardly believe anybody here will do the code for you. I believe the proposed solution covers just your original question. Any further implementation of the same with a database is to be addresses in a new question. Specially, that we do not know how your database looks like and what conditions we have to meet in order to do what. Good luck

Comment: Sometimes you just have to regret helping newbies. Your question was `how to change colors` based on a database trigger. How do you expect me to query your database that I can not see? My code changes your colors as requested, writing IF..THEN statements based on database rows is your own job. And thanks for the down-vote, people like you are making such communities ugly. No good luck wishes for you. :@